# solve indefinite integral

Tags: integration

I have this indefinite integral $\int 3 \sqrt{x}\,dx$ to solve.

My attempt:

$$\int 3 \sqrt{x}\,dx = 3 \cdot \frac {x^{\frac {1}{2} + \frac {2}{2}}}{\frac {1}{2} + \frac {2}{2}}$$

$$\int 3 \sqrt{x}\,dx = 3 \frac{x^{\frac {3}{2}}}{\frac {3}{2}} = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{9}{3} x^{\frac {3}{2}}$$

$$\int 3 \sqrt{x}\,dx = \frac{18}{3} x^{\frac{3}{2}} = 6 x^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

But according to wolframalpha the answer should be $2 x^{\frac {3}{2}}$

Where did I make a error in my calculation?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, try to write integration properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your penultimate step, $\frac 23$.$\frac 93$ $=\frac {18}{9}$ $=2$, not 6.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{9}{3}=2$. not $6$

Answer (score 2):

You failed in $\displaystyle\frac{2\cdot9}{3\cdot3} = \frac{18}{3}$, actually $\displaystyle\frac{2\cdot9}{3\cdot3} = \frac{2}{3}\cdot3 = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{3}{\left(\frac 3 2\right)} = 3\cdot\frac 2 3 \ne 3\cdot \frac 3 2.
$$